# Open two jquery datepickers simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery, uidatepicker

I have two input fields containing a class that triggers a datepicker to open. Both work fine independently, i.e when I click on one or the other but I want for both datepickers to open when either input field is clicked.

Here is the script part of the code

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

                    $( ".datefields" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',numberOfMonths: 1, yearRange: "2012:2014", changeYear: true, changeMonth: true});
```

and this is the html

```
<div id="quoteformcollection">
<h1>Collection</h1>

<input type"text" class="startTbl locationfields" id="AutoLocStart" value="Please Type a Collection Location"onclick="clearVal(this);"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="DepotStart" value=""/></td>

<input type="text" class="datefields" id="collectiondate" value="21/05/2012"/>
<input type"text" class="timefields" value="12:00" />
</div> 

<div id="quoteformreturn">
<h1>Return</h1>

<input type"text" class="locationfields" value="Enter the city or location for return" />
<input type"text" id="returndate" class="datefields" value="21/05/2012" />
<input type"text" class="timefields" value="12:00" />
</div>
```

I have tried looking for an answer myself but am quite new to jquery and struggling a bit so any help would be much appreciated.

I would also like for whatever value is selected in the first datepicker, for the default date in the second to be incremented by x number of days, which again I am not sure of the best way to go about it.

Any advice would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for instance to link the two datapickers:

```
$('#collectiondate').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "@",
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        var dateText = eval(dateText);
        var min = new Date();
        min.setTime(dateText);
        $('#end').datepicker('option', 'minDate', min);
    }
});

$('#returndate').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "@",
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd have to use the calendar 'inline' and manage how it's popped up yourself through jQuery / Javascript.  You need to point the cal to a div tag to use it inline.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#inline